# ValueError: Unrecognized Mode

Tags: python, image, psychopy

Here is my code:

```
import Image
img = Image.new("RBG",(649,489),(0,0,255))
for x in xrange(649):
    for y in xrange(489):
        img.putpixel((x,y),(0,255,0))

img.show()
```

When I try to run this code I get a "ValueError: unrecognized mode", does anyone know why this might happen? Any help will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: The psychopy-tag is a bit strange here since the code does not import anything from psychopy. Consider removing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess it should be `"RGB"` instead of `"RBG"`.

Comment: Oh man, that's embarrassing. Thanks a lot. :)